# Python: speed of conversion of type of 3d matrix element

Tags: python, performance, matrix, type-conversion

I believe that this is simple question, but I'm new to Python so any suggestion will be appreciated.
I have matrix of strings, and I need to convert every element into float type and then to increase it for some number. I did that like this:

```
for i in range(0,len(matrix)):
    for j in range(0,len(matrix[i])):
        for k in range(0,len(matrix[j])):
            matrix[i][j][k] = float(matrix[i][j][k]) + 5.555
```

Is there any other way of doing this in order to increase speed? Performance is really low when I have matrix[50][50][50] or bigger.
Is there one-line method that could increase all elements at once?

Comment: The third for should be `for k in range(0,len(matrix[i][j])):` in general case although in your case of a quadratic matrix it doesn't matter.

Comment: The best speedup you will get by using [numpy](http://numpy.scipy.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you're doing array work in Python, it's best to use the numpy library if possible.

```
import numpy

matrix = numpy.asarray(matrix,dtype=numpy.float64) + 5.555
```

Answer (score 4):

There are low level optimisations that you can make to your code, such as moving the calls to range() outside of the loops so you are not creating a new list (or generator if you are using 3.x) every time round the loops.

However the big optimisation is to switch to using [numpy](https://numpy.org/), which will execute operations across the entire array in high performance C code.

Answer (score 2):

If `matrix` is compatible, then you could (and probably should) put it in a `numpy` array. It's a very handy library for numeric computations and comes with lots of functions: depending on what you want to do, you may also want to look at `scipy`.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(matrix)
a += 5.5555
```

Given some random data as an example:

```
from numpy.random import random_sample

>>> a = random_sample( (3, 3, 3) )
>>> a
array([[[ 0.98899266,  0.10761687,  0.7784259 ],
        [ 0.79253918,  0.450742  ,  0.46417501],
        [ 0.71733034,  0.26575819,  0.19360072]],

       [[ 0.41609296,  0.96195897,  0.32777537],
        [ 0.59527144,  0.96655918,  0.50073892],
        [ 0.70797323,  0.406036  ,  0.47092251]],

       [[ 0.8572665 ,  0.00076713,  0.25379833],
        [ 0.03426925,  0.59837259,  0.85390736],
        [ 0.78306972,  0.00238982,  0.28702393]]])
>>> a += 5.55555
>>> a
array([[[ 6.54454266,  5.66316687,  6.3339759 ],
        [ 6.34808918,  6.006292  ,  6.01972501],
        [ 6.27288034,  5.82130819,  5.74915072]],

       [[ 5.97164296,  6.51750897,  5.88332537],
        [ 6.15082144,  6.52210918,  6.05628892],
        [ 6.26352323,  5.961586  ,  6.02647251]],

       [[ 6.4128165 ,  5.55631713,  5.80934833],
        [ 5.58981925,  6.15392259,  6.40945736],
        [ 6.33861972,  5.55793982,  5.84257393]]])
```